# Even without SAS token in Azure I am able to open link

Tags: c#, azure

I am storing pdf in my blob storage upon click of button. I thought of adding SAS tokens which I am able to add. I am doing something similar to 'GetBlobSasUri()' mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-2 and then I am saving that url. I am able to generate a SAS token and it is getting attached with the link I am saving in the blob. And after the token expires I am not able to open the url. But if I remove the SAS token which I added to the link, I am able to open the pdf document. I checked the access policy to make sure it is private. But it didn't help as in private mode I am able to open the pdf document by simply removing the SAS token.

And I am also wondering is it possible to add SAS token each time a PDF document opens. So that if one sends the url to somebody, that person will not be able to open the link once the token has expired. Right now what I have is on click of button a pdf is generated by storing it in blob and it has a SAS token appended to it.

I am also storing the token in my database along with the url to open pdf, does that make sense?

Can someone please suggest!

Comment: How are you accessing the blob? By URL, or making a call programmatically? If programmatically, then you *always* have access, since you use the account name + key. You cannot visit a private blob via just the url, unless it has a SAS appended to it. Please edit your question to include more details.

Comment: Also, I don't know what you mean, when you say you're storing the token along with the url. You mean you're storing the *SAS* token? Not sure why you'd do that, since you can generate a new URL (including SAS) at any time.

Comment: I have a button which generates a pdf by storing it in blob so I am appending the SAS token with the link to open the pdf. I am doing something similar to GetBlobSasUri() mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-2

Comment: @DavidMakogon- 
I am storing the link which opens the pdf and that link has a SAS token attached to it.

Answer (score 3):

What is the container access level? Is it public or blob? It needs to be private if you don't want the URL (w/o the SAS token) to work.

Also, I agree with David; I wouldn't store the security token in your database. It should be generated as needed. You'll have to write something to generate it. It's not clear how you're serving the PDF Files to the user. To do what you're asking, you would need an app that would let the user select one, and then the app would give the user a URL with a SAS token on it that expires in a few minutes. There's no way that I know of for a PDF file to get a SAS token or generate a SAS Token on its own.

Comment: In answer to how you can generate a SAS token on its own: you can do this via the portal. On the account level you can navigate to the"Shared Access Signature" blade and generate a SAS that would work for all blobs. You can also do this at the container level via the portal via an Access Policy. I suspect that the poster is currently doing one of these things. There are much more options if you generate them via code.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd Those are Account SAS keys. Not blob access keys (and you wouldn't give out an Account SAS to an end user). You must generate a SAS key for each blob you wish to provide an expiring link to (or attach a Shared Access Policy to a blob's URI, which can then be managed differently).

Comment: @DavidMakogon I totally agree that you shouldn't give out an account SAS key. However, you CAN create an account key  with service "blob" and with allowed reasource type "Object". This SAS token can be appended to the uri of any blob in the account. The only way you could revoke it then is to regenerate the source key, which would also revoke every other SAS given out.
(Sorry if that's what you already meant. I'm trying to clarify all of this in my own mind because I've got an exam coming up).

Comment: @AndrewShepherd - not sure if you realize the security hole you're suggesting. Basically you'd be allowing anyone to copy off that SAS and take "educated guesses" at other blob names, and start viewing content they should never view. This, contrasted with a resource-specific SAS that's tied to that resource. So no, the OP should *not* use the account-level SAS to append to blobs. Anyway - these comments, under Robin's answer, are *not* the place to debate this.

Comment: @DavidMakogon : Not a suggestion - just an interesting way to shoot yourself in the foot. I like pointing these out because it gives us a thorough insight as to how the technology is put together. 
The 'educated guess' scenario is a good one. You can apply the same argument against container-based SAS's - it should apply only to the blob.

(Incidentally a blob-specific SAS can't be created via the portal, only via the code. The Azure team seem to have haphazardly picked a smattering of tasks and added them to the portal, while not adding other tasks. That's going to confuse newcomers.)

Comment: @RobinShahan- I am having private access container as I mentioned in question also I made sure it is private.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd- i am able to generate a SAS token and it is getting attached with the link I am saving in the blob. I am doing something similar to 'GetBlobSasUri()'  mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-2 and then saving that url.

Comment: @Tina Please... ***stop adding details here***. *Edit your question*. You and Andrew have turned this into a discussion. If you want to continue, by all means take this to [chat](chat.stackoverflow.com). But there is no value adding detail here, and discussing this under an answer

Comment: @AndrewShepherd My answer was predicated on the assumption that Tina was looking for something automated where the user could select a file, and it would return a URL with an SAS on it. If you just want to retrieve an SAS for a  file, I recommend using the Azure Storage Explorer (storageexplorer.com), which is free, and will allow you to do that. Also, Tina, you should edit your original question to add the details and more info about what you are trying to accomplish if you want additional help. Also, if your container is marked private, a URI won't work w/o an SAS.

Answer (score 0):

Although question is old, this will help someone looking for solution.

Please check access level for the file itself along with parent container. Setting this to private will make sure URL without token would not work.  You should get ErrorCode, "ResourceNotFound".

Also, since this token is meant to be short lived, it should not be stored in Database and should be generated on-the-fly.

As a best security practice, tokens should not be stored in Database. You could store them in Azure KeyValult or similar.